# Join tables by datetime excluding seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that I need to join based on the datetime column but on the other table my datetime also includes seconds. My tables are as follows with their datatypes:

Table: `Carrots`

Columns:

```
Date (datetime) -> with example value "2023-09-13 23:00:12.000"
Hour (int)
Carrot (float)
```

Example data:

```
Date                      Hour      Carrot
-------------------------------------------
2023-09-08 17:00:25.000     17       0,015
2023-09-14 03:00:16.000      3      10,793
2023-09-14 04:00:18.000      4      10,78
2023-09-15 16:00:28.000     16       0,197
2023-09-15 17:00:29.000     17      10,239
```

Table: `Prices`

Columns:

```
Date (DateTime) -> with example value "2023-09-13 23:00:00.000"
Price (float)
Hour (int)
```

Example data:

```
Date                        Price       Hour
--------------------------------------------
2023-09-14 00:00:00.000     0,0176      0
2023-09-14 01:00:00.000     0,0192      1
2023-09-14 02:00:00.000     0,0181      2
2023-09-14 03:00:00.000     0,0177      3
2023-09-14 04:00:00.000     0,0176      4
2023-09-14 05:00:00.000     0,0181      5
2023-09-14 06:00:00.000     0,0199      6
2023-09-14 07:00:00.000     0,0318      7
2023-09-14 08:00:00.000     0,1286      8
2023-09-14 09:00:00.000     0,1257      9
2023-09-14 10:00:00.000     0,1108     10
2023-09-14 11:00:00.000     0,0992     11
2023-09-14 12:00:00.000     0,0663     12
2023-09-14 13:00:00.000     0,034      13
2023-09-14 14:00:00.000     0,0286     14
2023-09-14 15:00:00.000     0,0278     15
2023-09-14 16:00:00.000     0,0268     16
2023-09-14 17:00:00.000     0,0285     17
2023-09-14 18:00:00.000     0,1255     18
2023-09-14 19:00:00.000     0,0555     19
2023-09-14 20:00:00.000     0,0306     20
2023-09-14 21:00:00.000     0,0305     21
2023-09-14 22:00:00.000     0,0273     22
2023-09-14 23:00:00.000     0,0227     23
2023-09-15 00:00:00.000     0,0203      0
2023-09-15 01:00:00.000     0,0051      1
2023-09-15 02:00:00.000     0,0031      2
```

How can I join these two together only using part of the datetime column?

So far I have tried with something that I have found from SO but I get too many results. I have 220 entries in the `Carrots` table but when running my query I get more than 5k results. My current query is:

```
SELECT
    c.Date,
    c.Hour,
    c.Carrot,
    p.Price
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT Date, Hour, Carrot FROM Carrots) c
JOIN
    Prices p ON CONVERT(DATE, c.Date) = CONVERT(DATE, p.Date)
```

Result what I am looking after would look like this:

```
Date                        Hour    Carrot   Price
---------------------------------------------------
2023 - 09 - 08 17:00:00.000     17   0,015
2023 - 09 - 14 03:00:00.000      3  10,793   0,0177
2023 - 09 - 14 04:00:00.000      4  10,78    0,0176
2023 - 09 - 15 16:00:00.000     16   0,197   0,0268
2023 - 09 - 15 17:00:00.000     17  10,239   0,0285
```

Comment: FIi, `float` is a terrible data type for a column called "price". Monetary values and base-2 values do *not* mix well.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You're converting to a date which removes the entire time component, not just the seconds

Comment: `dateadd(second, -1*datepart(second, My column), MyColumn)`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? `Datetrunc` is available in 2022.

Comment: This is 2017 version of SQL Server

Comment: @DaleK Subtracting the number of seconds sounds good, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select
  c."Date",
  c."Hour",
  c.Carrot,
  p.Price
from Carrots as c
left join Prices as p
  on p."Date" between dateadd(second, -datepart(second, c."Date"), c."Date") and
                      c."Date"
;
```

Result:

```
+-------------------------+------+--------+--------+
|          Date           | Hour | Carrot | Price  |
+-------------------------+------+--------+--------+
| 2023-09-08 17:00:25.000 |   17 | 0.015  | null   |
| 2023-09-14 03:00:16.000 |    3 | 10.793 | 0.0177 |
| 2023-09-14 04:00:18.000 |    4 | 10.780 | 0.0176 |
| 2023-09-15 16:00:28.000 |   16 | 0.197  | 0.0268 |
| 2023-09-15 17:00:29.000 |   17 | 10.239 | 0.0285 |
+-------------------------+------+--------+--------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QOcnALlR).
If the values in the `c."Date"` column are contain minutes, then `dateadd(second, -datepart(second, c."Date"), c."Date")` can be rewritten as `dateadd(second, -datepart(minute, c."Date") * 60 - datepart(second, c."Date"), c."Date")`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with style 120 "ODBC canonical" `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` and limit the result to 16 characters, chopping off the number of seconds:

```
on    convert(varchar(16), c.Date, 120) = convert(varchar(16), p.Date, 120)
```

Comment: By replacing my current conversion with that I get 800k results

Comment: What do you see when you select a single Carrot row?  (Like `select * from (select top 1 * from carrot) c join Prices p ...`)